# Generate Javascript file with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, api, minify, sinemacula

## My current code

I have started writing an API that loads, minifies and returns javascript files into one file using PHP. This is achieved by pointing to a PHP file from a `script` tag in HMTL like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://libraries.sinemaculammviii.com/jsapi.php"></script>
```

This `jsapi.php` page processes the javascript files and outputs the minified javascript, with the header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

## My Question

Is this a bad method to load javascript files? Would it be **much** faster and reliable to load the javascript files individually by simply pointing to the `.js` file in the `src` attribute?

If you wish to see my code for the the full API, have a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18117/loading-javascript-libraries-with-php-api). The mentioned link also explains in detail what it is I am doing and why.

Comment: Nothing bad. Loading together speeds up your web application. You'd better hide your `php` file as `js`, this can be done with `.htaccess`

Comment: @BogdanBurim Yeah thats what I am going to do :-) If I rewrite the js file to php, will that mean that I do not have to output headers from PHP?

Comment: No, headers still will be needed. For IE7 (as far as I remember) at least (he is stupid).

Comment: @BogdanBurim Thought they might have been :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faster as .js yes, but marginally. The reason being that it would be a static file so wouldn't need the processing time PHP will take.

That said there's nothing wrong with feeding JavaScript through PHP like this. You could even come up with caching methods as well to reduce the processing impact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I thought to be honest :-) The reason I asked the question was simply because I was advised not to by the user that answered my question on the Code Review link supplied in the question