# Dynamic generation of JavaScript using PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I usually include javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/somejs.js">
```

is there a way like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/somephp.php?js=somejs">
```

So that the PHP Script echoes a custom generated string or file of requested name

If this is possible how should be the basic php syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Javascript file with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230411/generate-javascript-file-with-php)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : I dint try because i didn't know how to return such a file from server

Comment: @JohnConde :Sorry. Next time i'd follow the way you suggested. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `script` tag doesn't care whether the URL it's pointed at ends with '.js' or not. If you point it at some URL that will serve valid javascript, then you're all good, whether that URL ends in '.js' or '.php' or anything else, and whether the mechanism for serving it is your apache server serving a file straight from the file system, a PHP file echoing out the javascript, or anything else that you please.

If you do decide to serve JavaScript by echoing it out via PHP, to be neat and correct you should set the content type header to 'application/javascript' by calling `header('Content-type: application/javascript');` respectively.

Comment: Setting the content-type header from php as text/javascript is also recommended.

Comment: You can also do this trick to serve CSS.

Comment: @bfavaretto True, and added to my answer. (Although as far as I know browsers all ignore the content-type of stuff pointed to by `script` tags so there's no context in which it has any practical effect?)

Comment: @bfavaretto `"application/javascript"` [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4101763/59461)

Answer (score 2):

As @Mark Amery said it can be done just as you shown, but you should probably include

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

It will most probably work in all browsers even without it but browsers will complain about it silently.

Chrome throws this for example in the console if you don't include `header` part:

> Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain