# Generate javascript file with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have done generating client side js file from php like below

[Generate Javascript file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230411/generate-javascript-file-with-php)

Curious to know how same can be done in nodejs i'm using dustjs as server side template

```
<script src="/myjs.js"></script>


app.get('/myjs.js', function (req, res) {

    res.render('myjs'); //myjs can be a  template 

});
```

Comment: If you're asking, "can I point a script tag's src attribute to a file that is generated dynamically by a NodeJS server", the answer is yes.  That's more or less what your example code is doing.  Otherwise...what are you asking?

Comment: can i have standalone page which connects to mongodb or different modules, fetch some data and out put the result as js.    

  I think the best bet is to pass the data with render and construct

    


    app.get('/myjs.js', function (req, res) {

        res.render('myjs',{name:"myname"}); //myjs can be a  template 

    });